# Why is my correct answer deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I answered a longer question for which there turns out to be a relatively simple answer in a relatively simple way. A user complained that my answer was just an opinion and anyone could oppose it. I disagreed citing support for my answer and challenging the user to post an opposing opinion if that's the way we roll here. The user claimed my answer didn't follow the rules (and also that answers here aren't opinions--which, if you really think about it, is a tad absurd). Except it does. It directly answers the question but (as admitted) doesn't do much more. The comment chain digressed. Then my answer got deleted.

[image: deleted answer]

Was the deletion performed in order to punish me for my comments? If the comment is the concern, why not just delete the comment? Or is there some rule the answer violated that makes it unfit? I've read the rules plenty of times (a certain someone has made sure of that). It's a real answer, I promise.

I posted the answer again, but it was again deleted with similar claims that it does not meet the criteria for a good answer. Can someone please tell me what it is violating?

Comment: And I should add, no offense to the helpful people around here. I come here every once and awhile to try an help out. Half the time a selection community leaders simply decide to piss all over my contributions. It's real annoying and honestly I'm on my last straw. I've seen others leave this place permanently after citing similar complaints over the years. This isn't some crusade. It's a Q/A forum with a topic and some guidelines FFS.

Comment: Although the answer was indeed deleted by a moderator, your comment discussion was with a regular user.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I thought that user was a moderator in the past. Perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @DocBrown.

Comment: @Yannis: yes, you are right, did so now.

Comment: Well that doesn't explain why influential people here are allowed to break the rules. Yet when I clearly follow them, I get harassed. If you *really, truly* believe what you've told me about opinion Q/A and answer content, then go flag your top two answers. One is a question that, if I posted it, would be closed as not constructive or primarily opinion based. The other one would be considered a low quality answer because it does not cite any references or provide any explanation and is ***literally*** the definition of an opinion. (How many classes before I unit test? *I think* one is enough.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much to add over Doc Brown's comments on this question. We have guidance on [what makes a good answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). We also expect that answers explain how and why it helps the asker. I don't see how it answers the questions asked of how to safely work with namespaces.

Comment: The op has since clarified with that additional addendum. Initially the question literally ended with the line: "I've seen this solution used before, but what happens if someone still re-defines my variable?" I really don't know how to answer that other than to say, pick a better name--that's the point of a global namespace. If you expect answers to contain explanations and not simply answers, please add that to your page. But as it sits, the guidelines concede, "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better". My answer was concise and correct. I'm sorry it didn't suite *you*.

Comment: @DavidCowden Your answer didn't suit the community. Your first answer was getting flags for being low quality. Your second answer was flagged because it was a duplicate of a deleted post for low quality. The correct thing to do is to edit the post to make it better, not continually repost a low quality post.

Comment: gnat flags every damn thing I post. I'm pretty sick of it and honestly I just don't care anymore. I've tried editing things to fix them, they never get reassessed. My top answer here is on a question that initially was closed because y'all could not fathom how there could be an objective answer. Turns out there actually was a pretty objective response which *in the least* is helpful for other people seeking similar info. But that doesn't matter. And can you honestly say there aren't opinion based threads here? You can't. As far as I'm concerned this community has some nepotism issues.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe gnat's comment did not explain well to you what was wrong (in your attempt to answer [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340034/how-to-create-a-safe-namespace-for-my-application-in-javascript)), but Thomas Owens (who deleted your question) was IMHO right. Let me explain why.

Since I have trouble to understand what you are trying to say with this short statement, and how it answers the OPs question, I guess other readers probably had the same problem. That is why I guess why you got those downvotes.  If you write an answer, you better try to be constructive. A good answer would either contain an explanation *how* the OP can solve his problem, or *why* you think it does not need a solution, or *why* you think there is no good solution in Javascript.

Oh, and the picture was surely intendend to be funny, but I don't think it is really clarifying.

Comment: Well the image was an animation of a dog chasing its tail. I thought it clarified the point perfectly. It seems people disagree. It was not intended to solely be funny. And even if that was the case, since when is humor not okay?

Comment: And honestly this is exactly the issue I'm having. My answer was not incorrect, it simply lacked something according to you, Thomas, gnat. What it lacks has yet to be clearly identified. Sure it's terse, but not incorrect. The op is effectively expressing frustration at what they see as a shortcoming in JS and then also citing the solution to the shortcoming in the question *and then* asking what happens if someone  still decides to clobber their namespace. I mean we really don't need to digress into a finer discussion on the definition of a namespace.

Comment: Furthermore, gnat's 2nd highest voted answer is an answer in the same format: one or two lines that have no links to references but which tersely answer the question, "how soon should I unit test". I don't live here, I come here occasionally when I see an interesting thread from the emails or have some spare cycles. Things like this send mixed messages to me. And for what it's worth, the answer would have been perfectly fine on stackoverflow. Also OPs question is not novel. A search for javascript namespaces yields plenty of discussion. I don't think that type of knowledge needs explanation.

Comment: Well, it seems gnat actually tried to tell you your answer was too terse to be understood well by others, but from your reaction, I assume you did not get the message - may not be your fault, communication is typically a matter of two persons. If you think the question is not novel and you found a good existing explanation, it would have been helpful you posted a link, or mark the question as a possible duplicate of another existing one on this site.

Comment: I mean that's the thing, terse is a pretty relative assessment and gnat didn't say my answer was too terse he said it sounded like an opinion. That is a different message. And I prefer to start off with simple answers and evolve them as needed to clarify or as they become more popular. On the flip side, I would also argue that a 5 paragraph essay for each question is not really that helpful either. I get pretty irked when people use their influence inconsistently. I'm happy to abide by rules, but please don't try to tell me that terse answers which happen to incorporate a gif are unacceptable.

Comment: @DavidCowden: Honestly, I think your answer was so terse and contained so few explanation that it is not very astonishing that another person reads it as an opionion. Why don't you edit your initial answer, add a short explanation which even me - who is not fluent in Javascript, having only a vague notion where the OPs problem is - can understand what is going on there, and ask Thomas for reassessment. I can assure you, Thomas is a very cooperative moderator, he will be much easier to convince that your answer is now a good one than - lets say other guys here.